# GraphQl usług Gateway pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, graphql, graphql-java

1)  Gateway pattern from EAA Catalog
The complexity of “business microservices” was hidden by using a Gateway pattern. This component was responsible for the proper redirection of requests to the appropriate services based on the configuration. The frontend application could only communicate with this component.

Link: 
https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html

I am wondering how `GraphQl` can handle this pattern? 
How we can implement this pattern if we have one `GraphQl` endpoint per microservice?

**Responding to answer - Edit:**

In my project there is architecture then there is gateway, and `zuul` sends it to another one (it knows by `URL` From request). `GraphQl` is one endpoint so `zuul` wont work.
**So we have only two steps (always - can check that in `zipkin` for example) like:**

`Gateway microservice` -> `Microservice X`

Regarding:

> Maybe you implement another GraphQL API that consolidate these
>   microservices 's GraphQL API

That is the way i was thinking.
In my project only `API gateway` would be available to the `internet`.
But in this case i am wondering if we got in the query like, 5 `queries` to microservice `A` and 3 `queries` to microservice `B` how can I pass them in this microservice gateway - i do not want to cut it piece by piece so i will send one by one (sum up to 3) queries to microservice B from it - but 3 in one shot.
The same goes for microservice A -> i want to send from `graphQL` in one shot.

If i use only these:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version> <!--5.0.2 http://localhost:8999/graphiql fails to load-->
    </dependency>
```

Then in `microservice X` I got schema and some queries like:

```
type Query {
    getAllItems: [TestEntity]
    getDataTypes: [DictionaryType]
    (...)
}
```

And in controller i have:

```
private DataFetcher<List<TestEntity>> allDictionaryItemsFetcher;
private DataFetcher<Set<DictionaryType>> dictionaryTypeFetcher;

@Value("classpath:test.graphqls")
private Resource schemaResource;
private GraphQL graphQL;
(...)
        allDictionaryItemsFetcher = dataFetchingEnvironment -> dictionaryService.getAllDictionaryItemsAsStrings();
        dictionaryTypeFetcher = dataFetchingEnvironment -> dictionaryService.getDictionaryTypes();


@PostConstruct
private void loadSchema() throws IOException {
    File schemaFile = schemaResource.getFile();
    TypeDefinitionRegistry registry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaFile);
    RuntimeWiring wiring = buildWiring();
    GraphQLSchema schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(registry, wiring);
    graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
}

private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            .type("Query", typeWriting -> typeWriting
                    .dataFetcher("getAllItems", allDictionaryItemsFetcher)
                    .dataFetcher("getDataTypes", dictionaryTypeFetcher)

            )
            .build();
}
```

Then if we make `Gateway microservice` with the same depedencies regarding `GraphQl` we will have in `schema`:

```
type Query {
    getAllItems: [TestEntity] # from microservice A
    getDataTypes: [DictionaryType] # from microservice A
    (...) # Other from microservice A,B,C,(...)
}
```

Then if user sends in `one request`
get me `getAllItems` and `getDataTypes` from `Microserivce A` and get `Z` `resources` from `microservice B`
how can i send two queries:
first with `getAllItems` and `getDataTypes`  to `Microservice A`
second with `Z` requests to`microservice B` ?

How can i separete `GraphQL` requests that way?

I do not want to send reuqests one by one - for example when i get:
get me `getAllItems` and `getDataTypes` from `Microserivce A`
I do not want to call twice `Microservice A` once with:
 `getAllItems`
and second time with `getDataTypes` .

How can I easily separete the queries by `microservice` only ?

For example making many `schemas` (one per `microservice) in`GraphQL gateway`and`configuring`one endpoint with many`schemas` - is it possible? Or some other way to solve it?

Maybe it comes of my misunderstanding `GraphQL` but i think in the `case` above we have to configue one `GraphQl` per `microservice` in `java`.

I do not want an `GraphQL gateway` that shoots to `microservice X` with classic `REST` api (not `GraphQL`), cause of many of stuff that we lose that way, for example `fetching optimization` see here:
https://youtu.be/1zIHHi2MaQE?t=1369
Or making `N` requests instead of `one` to concrete `microservice X`

Answer (score 3):

Basically it means the following architecture. GraphQL API is the gateway which sits in front of different APIs such as legacy Soap API , REST Microservice API , 3rd-partly API ,database or blalablab.

[image]
*Pics taken from [this](https://www.howtographql.com/basics/3-big-picture/)*

> This component was responsible for the proper redirection of requests
>   to the appropriate services based on the configuration.

Each field of the GraphQL type/query/mutation has their own resolver function which define their own logic to get the values from different back-end services .So GraphQL type system and its resolver functions are a kind of configuration that defines how the requests redirect to the appropriate services to get the data.

> Gateway pattern from EAA Catalog The complexity of "business
>   microservices" was hidden by using a Gateway pattern. The fronted
>   application could only communicate with this component.

Before adding a GraphQL API ,to get the data to displayed in UI. User may first call `FooService` to get a part of data .Then based on some `FooService` data , he has to call `BarService` to get another part of data. Then based on some `BarService` data , he has to call `BazService` to get another data. Then based on some `BazService` , he has to blablabla........  which is a very tedious and troublesome process. Not to mention that different APIs use different names to represent the same business concept.

After adding a GraphQL API , we move these troublesome work to GraphQL API .User only need to communicate with GraphQL API directly (So it is a **Gateway**).They just call one API to get the data they want rather than calling many APIs.

Also , GraphQL consolidates the business concepts that has different names and interpretation in different services in one API. So from the user point of view , it hides the complexity of "business microservices" as it is more easier to use develop

> How we can implement this pattern if we have one GraphQl endpoint per
>   microservice?

Maybe you implement another GraphQL API that consolidate these microservices 's GraphQL API

Comment: I've updated the question - I also thought of ```Maybe you implement another GraphQL API that consolidate these microservices 's GraphQL API```
but i have concern here.

Comment: Please ask me in the comment if there is something  I did not write clear enough.
By approach of `GraphQL gateway` (only avaible in the internet) -> other `microservices` with `GraphQL` we can cut easily what is available by `schema` in the `GraphQL gateway` component. This i helpful if we have for example many products / internal `queries` etc